# Autogeneration of tests and stubs with CUnit

Tags: testing, stub, cunit

Does anybody know of a free/commercial tool that would automatically generate tests and stubs for C code to work with CUnit framework?

Answer (score 2):

Try CMock for generating stub implementations of header files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **[netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html)** will do it.